# What is the latest stable Flutter build to be using Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add Firebase authentication to my app. I've gone through the [process of linking firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup) with my app, but when I get to Step 4.6 and try running my app with the Firebase plugins installed, I get the following error:

```
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.0.2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated A
PI.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_analytics-7.1.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseanalytics\FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java uses or overrides a depre
cated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-1.0.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated A
```

From what I understand, I need to wait for the Firebase team to update their plugins before I can use them with the latest version of Flutter

```
Flutter 2.0.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 8962f6dc68 (2 weeks ago) • 2021-03-11 13:22:20 -0800
Engine • revision 5d8bf811b3
Tools • Dart 2.12.1
```

Does anyone know the latest stable build that the Firebase API works on? These particular errors don't stop the build from completing, however if I try to use the playstore plugin, for example, it crashes the build script. For now I'll try to find a compatible stable build myself. I'll update this post when I find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest stable flutter build is 2.0.3. Many Firebase plugins have been migrated already to null-safety. Everything is working as a charm for me while using latest versions of dependencies for Firebase from Pub.dev, even for flutter web.

I think it might be something in the play-store plugin implementation however.

Comment: I'll try out the latest Flutter version. What channel is Flutter 2.0.3 on? I was sure I had updated to the latest build on the Stable channel today.

Comment: Flutter 2.0.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4d7946a68d (8 days ago) • 2021-03-18 17:24:33 -0700
Engine • revision 3459eb2436
Tools • Dart 2.12.2

Comment: Thanks for this answer. 2.0.3 was indeed available. Usually the latest Flutter build is abailable through my IDE, but this time I had to update it through console. That's why when I updated earlier today I didn't get 2.0.3. And it indeed works with firebase-auth without deprecation issues.